# Create ViewControllers and make them downloadable

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a project. Project has a lot of `ViewContrllers`. And taking a lot of space in phone. I wonder if there is any way to make `ViewContrllers` loading as packages.

For example user selects main menu, main menu and 3 another `ViewContrllers` associated with it will be downloaded and as soon as the user quits the app they can be erased from the phone.

I know it causes a lot of data usage. But i just wonder is it possible to upload your `ViewContrllers` on cloud and download them in app when using and remove them after using.

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean by uploading and/or downloading view controllers. Those are part of your application's code. Are you maybe referring to images or data instead?

Comment: Correct my if i am wrong, Are you expecting your code of the view controllers to be downloaded from internet and then be packaged and executed dynamically??

Comment: My guess is you keep segueing from one controller to the next with popping or dismissing so your nav stack is out of control.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- You could use some kind of React Native, or equivalent, solution.
- You could define your View Controllers as JSON and configure a specialised UIViewController with this JSON.

Those ideas aside, I don't think view controllers as XIBS, Storyboard, or in code, should be detrimental to the size of the app.